# Email CSS not applied in production. Premailer-rails with TailwindCSS on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tailwind-css, actionmailer, premailer

##### Background

Tailwind is set-up using the `cssbundling-rails` gem which bundles all CSS into a single file: `app/assets/builds/application.tailwind.css`.

In dev env, emails are correctly rendered as `premailer-rails` turns the (tailwind) CSS classes into inline styles. I use mailcatcher to preview emails.  This works because of the reference to the stylesheet in `layouts/mailer.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

##### Problem

In production env (heroku), emails are not rendered with CSS. The CSS classess have been removed without being replaced by inline-styles.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" %>` by any chance